# Error when i refresh page in dynamics crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

i become an error when i click of the refresh button in Quote Entity.
the Problem does not happen in every record.
here is the error Text:
   TypeError: Unable to get property 'getValue' of undefined or null reference at initializeFields

(https://.crm4.dynamics.com/%7b637228466560015635%7d/webresources/Sales/QuoteDetail/QuoteDetail_main_system_library.js:1:8424)
   at FormOnLoad (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/%7b637228466560015635%7d/webresources/Sales/QuoteDetail/QuoteDetail_main_system_library.js:2:11491)
   at mp.prototype.executeFunction (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:1429:2767)
   at mp.prototype.execute (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:1429:2419)
   at up.prototype._executeIndividualEvent (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:1426:19561)
   at up.prototype._executeEventHandler (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:1426:18254)
   at execute (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:1426:15493)
   at O.prototype._executeSyncAction (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:881:688)
   at O.prototype._executeSync (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:881:294)
   at O.prototype.executeAction (https://.crm4.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.476-2003.4:881:150)

Comment: I'm sure not if this is a programming problem where the [mcve] is missing or a bug report that should be directed at the developers of Dynamics CRM. Either way, the question doesn't seem suitable for Stackoverflow in its current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an Error because of Javascript and especially for your function `initializeFields`

Your Javascript is running onLoad of your Form.

You are fetching some attribute, and trying to get value of it.

But you do not get object itself and hence getValue Error.

Try adding your code here and we can help you further.